# Load image from Parse to Image view

Tags: android, parse-platform

I loaded ParseFile to an arraylist photos.
But now i wanna show it in ImageView?

```
ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("photo");
        query.setLimit(2000);
        List<ParseObject> listA = query.find();
        for (ParseObject mPhoto : listA) {
            Photo newPhoto = new Photo();
            newPhoto.setImage((ParseFile) mPhoto.get("imageFile"));
            newPhoto.setTrade_id((String) mPhoto.get("trade_id"));
            photos.add(newPhoto);
        }
    } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How i can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. This will show you how to display 1 `image` for 1 `ParseFile`. If you want to display all image in `arraylist` you should save `Bitmap object` to `arraylist` instead of `ParseFile object`.

```
 ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object
    .get("imageFile");
fileObject
    .getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

        public void done(byte[] data,
            ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Decode the Byte[] into
                // Bitmap
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(
                        data, 0,
                        data.length);

                // initialize
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

                // Set the Bitmap into the
                // ImageView
                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            } else {
                Log.d("test",
                    "Problem load image the data.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Another way is you need to get the url of the image
`String imageUrl = parseFileObject.getUrl();`

then use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for load image

**Note** : You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with Parse for performance and synchronous

Hope this help

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my mind , I wanna show the ParseFile in my ArrayList , not load again in Parse, because i loaded it before.

Comment: I think it is the guide for you, you should modify it again for suitable with your code. 
in my code I show you how to create a `bitmap` from `ParseFile`, then how to display `bitmap` in `Imageview`. Then instead of save `ParseFile` in your arraylist you should save `Bitmap` in your arraylist

Comment: Because i load data in Application , and in activitity user can sreach information , then onClick in information and show .

Comment: im my idie i wanna save ParseFile in Arraylist and then corvet ParseFile to Bitmap and save it in ArrayList<Bitmap>

Comment: @EvanNgo Of cource your idea should work but I think my idea is a little better.

Comment: and what sould i do if i wanna find photo with ID and load it ?

Comment: `(ParseFile) object.get("imageFile");` // object here is ParseObject

Comment: my skype id is phanvanlinh94qt. contact me if possible

Comment: do you have Facebook address @@ i'm vietnamese :3

Comment: i cannot use facebook :), contact me at phanvanlinh.94vn@gmail.com. we can hangout

Comment: i'm installing Skype :)

Comment: @EvanNgo ok, I'm waiting

Answer (score 1):

Well you have Array of Images,so if you want to display all of them pass `ArrayList<photo>` to `CustomAdpater` and using `ListView` you can Display the whole thing

like
**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomAdpater.java

```
public class CustomAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomAdpater(Context context, int resourceId,
            ArrayList<Photo> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Photo rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImage());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply a way to set image to your imageView is Setting up Bitmap variables. Use Getter method of your Photo class and set That to Bitmap variable.

```
Bitmap yourImage = newPhoto.getImage(); //Gets the image and set to yourImage variable
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourId)
imageView.setImageBitmap(yourImage);
```

You can use Properties of BitmapFactory class as per needed to decode and store in variable..